# Black only has pawns: Mate in what?

Tags: problems, checkmate

In a standard opening position in chess, imagine that all Black pieces are removed except for the king and pawns.

```
[FEN "4k3/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQ - 0 1"]
```

What is the shortest forced mate, assuming White starts?

I don't know the answer to this but it seems like a fun piece of chess trivia if it is solvable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Having run stockfish for a couple of days, I can confirm there is at least a mate in 15.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Stockfish took a long time with this one, but with some help it eventually got to [here.](https://lichess.org/study/FJKaViJU)

Looks like it's *approximately* checkmate in 15 from your position. By move 9 (following Stockfish recommendations) it finds a checkmate in 6. Here's what Stockfish says is the best line:

```
[FEN "4k3/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQ - 0 1"]

1. c3 b5 2. Qb3 c6 3. Qa3 a5 4. Qxa5 e5 5. Qc7 f6 6. Qc8+ Ke7 7. Qg8 e4 8. Qxg7+ Ke6 9. g3 f5 10. d4 e3 11. Bh3 b4 12. Bxf5+ Kxf5 13. Qf7+ Kg5 14. Bxe3+ Kg4 15. f3#
```

Here's a sample game, me vs Stockfish. Took me 18 moves: https://lichess.org/AJFXfWmCQB5I

And another, also 18 moves: https://lichess.org/Ibno7F6cdfhT

I missed some sequences both times.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something but for me your link shows the board, but no moves

Comment: Woops. My mistake. I'll see if I can get the move order in my answer

Comment: If you're struggling just cut and paste the text of the moves and someone (e.g. me) will make it suitable for the  replayer. Or look at https://chess.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179/how-do-i-add-a-replayer-to-my-post

Comment: @IanBush crud, I can't get the starting FEN to work right. Would you mind editing it, or telling me how? I feel kind of goofy now lol.

Comment: Black can play 11. ... ef2+ just to lengthen the game one more omve

Comment: @yrodro in which game?

Comment: The board I see in your answer has all the pieces at the start for both black and white. Is that a mistake?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Stockfish has managed to find a mate in 16 so far for me.  I will leave it running and see if this improves.  e3 appears to be the best first move for white.

Comment: It has now found mates in 15, just as you suspected.

Comment: OK, cool. And sorry about that display board...not sure why it won't take my FEN for the starting position. @Anush

Comment: @Brandon_J I've fixed it; you need "halfmove clock" and "fullmove number" (just `0 1` works), see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forsyth%E2%80%93Edwards_Notation#Definition). Also, there needs to be a line break between the FEN tag and the move list.